# Angular variable reverts to original value after change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ui-router` to manage the state for the admin section a project. The admin section has a place to navigate categories. Within this category management section, I'm attempting to build a breadcrumb link system.

My problem is that I'm using a $scope variable to hold the name of the currently selected subcategory (or breadcrumb), but it won't hold the new value. It very quickly inserts the new value, but then reverts to the original "Top Level" category.

The subcategory is a child of the category and look like this in the ui-router:

```
.state('admin.category', {
...
},
.state('admin.category.subcategory', {
...
},
```

category.html ("0" indicates the top level of all categories)

```
<a ui-sref="admin.category.subcategory({categoryId: 0})" ng-click="breadCrumbManager(0)">View Categories</a>

<div ui-view></div>
```

subcategory.html (breadCrumbLinks is the var that won't hold the new value)

```
<div>

{{breadCrumbLinks}}

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <a ui-sref="admin.category.subcategory({categoryId: category.id})" ng-click="breadCrumbManager(category.id)">{{category.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>
```

AdminController (where the name switching occurs)

```
$scope.breadCrumbManager = function(categoryId) {

if (categoryId === 0)
{
    console.log("top level");
    $scope.breadCrumbLinks = "Top Level"; //keeps switching to this!
}
else
{
    categoryService.getCategoryName(categoryId).then(function(link){

        console.log(link); //logs correctly
        $scope.breadCrumbLinks = link;
        //$scope.breadCrumbLinks = "sub level";

    });
}
}
```

The newly assigned breadcrumb name logs to the console correctly, and there isn't an extra call to this function upon page load, so I can't figure why it reverts back. There should be a log entry in the console if that happened, but there isn't. Also, the system for displaying categories works fine.

Plus, this function is accessed with ng-click, and each link has it's own value. It's not like I can click two links at once. Really stumped here.

*** Edit ****

I've commented out the portion that fetches the category name for now. Now, it's a simple if statement that logs the categoryId and where it's being called from:

```
$scope.breadCrumbManager = function(categoryId) {

if (categoryId === 0)
{
    $scope.breadCrumbLinks = "Top Level";
    console.log(categoryId + " is top level");
}
else
{
    $scope.breadCrumbLinks = "bottom Level";
    console.log(categoryId + " is bottom level");

        /*categoryService.getCategoryName(categoryId).then(function(link){

            $scope.breadCrumbLinks = link;

        });*/
}
}
```

It's still displaying "Top Level"!! If I manually change `0` to an actual category id on the `category.html` page, it will display "bottom level". Which leads me to believe that it has something to do with calling the `breadCrumbManager()` function from the `admin.category.subcategory` route.

What that is? I have no idea. The function is being called, the data is right, but Angular will not update the variable. I think I'm going to ditch Angular until 2.0 arrives. 80% of my problems on this project are trying to figure out angular quirks like this.

Comment: Can you repro this in a plunker?

Comment: I feel that if you abstracted the bread crumb manager to factory then you can hold state there. In a controller I think that the state could be fairly volatile. If you use the factory, you can use events to update the controller when the bread crumb changes

Comment: I would still have to assign it to $scope.breadCrumbLinks at some point though, right? How else would it display on the page? I'm not even worried about fetching the breadcrumbs at this point. I just want the text to change if it's not ==0.

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, pull out that logic into a factory, have it fire off events. Create plnkr and I can show you.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting the breadcrumb data into a service solved this particular problem. It still feels like a an unnecessary level added to the application in order to get this work. I added the following to my service:

```
sailsCommerceApp.factory("categoryService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

var breadCrumbs = "Default";

....

addBreadCrumb: function(categoryId) {

if (categoryId == 0)
{
    breadCrumbs = "Top Level";
}
else
{
    breadCrumbs = "Bottom Level";
}

},

viewBreadCrumb: function() {

    return breadCrumbs;

}
```

Modified the controller to look like this:

```
$scope.breadCrumbManager = function(categoryId) {

categoryService.addBreadCrumb(categoryId);
$scope.breadCrumbLinks = categoryService.viewBreadCrumb();

}
```